# LINQ - SQL Display data in html table

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, html-table

I would like to perform a select statement using a DataContext from the code behind page and then display the results in an HTML table.

Best ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this as always depends. One of the fastest and easiest way would be to directly bind the data to a DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to create html table you can use a `literal` in frontend and add the literal text from back end
eg `<asp:Literal ID="ltrUser" runat="server"></asp:Literal>`
In backend code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var data = datasource;
            ltrUser.Text = "<table><tr><td>";
            ltrUser.Text += "<h1>"+ data.name + "</h1>";
            ltrUser.Text += "</td></tr></table>";
        }
```